# Image resolution and brower-resizing

Tags: html, css, image

I've got a couple questions about the use of images in a html document that I couldn't find an answer for.

- Why is the standard 12x12 / 24x24 / 48x48 / 96x96 /... and not 8x8 /
  16x16 / 32x32 / 64x64 / ... ?
- Why is a 130x130px image resized to 50x50px by the browser (by
  setting its width/height in the html doc) going to be more blurry
  than a 100x100 image resized to 50x50 ? (is it just easier for the
  browser to divide the size by 2 ?)
- Is there a specific resolution for images that is worth using over another to be
  more 4k friendly ? For instance using 384x384px images instead of
  96x96 for 4K screen owners ?

Comment: Your questions are too broad, speculative, and unclear. Your first question may not even be true. I'm not aware of any such standard.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Why are there icon size standards?

First of all there are no "standard" sizes for icons but it is always a good idea to create icons with a equal ratio = square images. That does not mean you are not allowed to break the rules, but it depens for which medium you are creating the icons. Android using a differend base size then iOS, because they need to support different resolutions. For desktop it is always good to start from a scale of 16px as a base. [reference for icon sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589462/industry-standard-icon-sizes)

---

#### 2. Why get images blurry when resizes?

Image you are the browser and you need to repaint your 120x120px pixel image into an 50x50 canvas. The problem you face right now is that you need to decides on several point which color to choose especially on edges? What the browser does ist to mix up colors for edges where he knows there is not more enoug space to display it crisp. This is causing the "blurry" effect. No think about resizing the 120x120 to the half. Thats a lot more easier because you dont need to mix colors anymore. Or in more technical term:

> Well rastered images when scaled in either direction are going to have some anomalies. When you make them bigger, it’s obvious – things get pixelated quickly. When you shrink them down, whatever is rendering it has to guess on what pixel goes where. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/scaling-down-images-with-css-makes-them-blurry/#post-188194

---

### 3. Are there a specific resolution for images

Thats basicly a very good question and opens the topic of "responsive" Images. As you know the pixen density on 4k Monitors / Smartphones is a lot higher then on regular screen. The fact that images cannot scale the informations by themself makes them pixelated when enlarged and blurry when shrinked. Best case would be to use SVG as often as you can, icons are best usecase for icons. Normally just putting the bigges image online would do the task, but performancewise it would be catastrophical. If you want to master this topic I can give you some good links to dive in:

- https://css-tricks.com/optimizing-large-scale-displays/
- https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/

Hope thats answers, at least, a bit of your worries :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is what I was looking for ! I was indeed wondering if svg would be the best way to solve theses issues since I am mostly concerned about the way my icons render on differents devices so I am glad you brought that up. Thanks for all the details !